# VirtualBoxのゲストがタイムアウトする(Error In supR3HardNtChildWaitFor)

Tags: virtualbox, selinux

VirtualBox関連の質問もされているようなので、こちらに失礼します。

環境:Windows 7 Professional 64bit
バージョン：5.0.10r104061
ゲストOS：CentOS 7

VirtualBoxでゲストOS起動時、`Creating process for virtual machine "ゲスト" (GUI/Qt) ... (1/2)`が表示されている最中に下記エラーが出ます。

```
タイトルバー：Error In supR3HardNtChildWaitFor
内容：Timed out after 600001 ms waiting for child request #1(CloseEvents).
(rc=258)

where: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor what: 5 Unknown Status 258(0x102)
(258) - Unknown Status(0x102)
```

そのエラーをOK（以前はAbortだったかと思います）した後に、

```
仮想マシン"ゲスト"のセッションを開けませんでした。

The virtual machine 'ゲスト' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\<myname>\VirtualBox VMs\ゲスト\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

終了コード : E_FAIL (0x80004005)
コンポーネント: MachineWrap
インターフェース: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}
```

が出ます。この後、OKを押した時、何度か繰り返した場合に起動することがあります。（遅くて起動していることに気づいていないだけで、起動しているのかもしれません）
ログの内容は

```
20b4.1bd8: Log file opened: 5.0.10r104061 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000014 g_uNtVerCombined=0x611db110
20b4.1bd8: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
20b4.1bd8:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:43.161971100Z
20b4.1bd8:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T01:09:05.164170200Z
20b4.1bd8:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.613612500Z
20b4.1bd8:     FileAttributes:  0x20
20b4.1bd8:     Size:            0x1a67c0
20b4.1bd8:     NT Headers:      0xe0
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x56259295
20b4.1bd8:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x56259295
20b4.1bd8:     Image Version:   6.1
20b4.1bd8:     SizeOfImage:     0x1a9000 (1740800)
20b4.1bd8:     Resource Dir:    0x14d000 LB 0x5a028
20b4.1bd8:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
20b4.1bd8:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
20b4.1bd8:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
20b4.1bd8:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
20b4.1bd8: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
20b4.1bd8:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:43.296978900Z
20b4.1bd8:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T01:05:40.819000000Z
20b4.1bd8:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.800812900Z
20b4.1bd8:     FileAttributes:  0x20
20b4.1bd8:     Size:            0x11c600
20b4.1bd8:     NT Headers:      0xe8
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x56259270
20b4.1bd8:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x56259270
20b4.1bd8:     Image Version:   6.1
20b4.1bd8:     SizeOfImage:     0x120000 (1179648)
20b4.1bd8:     Resource Dir:    0x117000 LB 0x528
20b4.1bd8:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
20b4.1bd8:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
20b4.1bd8:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
20b4.1bd8:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
20b4.1bd8: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
20b4.1bd8:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:43.047964600Z
20b4.1bd8:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T01:05:40.819000000Z
20b4.1bd8:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.800812900Z
20b4.1bd8:     FileAttributes:  0x20
20b4.1bd8:     Size:            0x67c00
20b4.1bd8:     NT Headers:      0xe8
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x56259271
20b4.1bd8:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x56259271
20b4.1bd8:     Image Version:   6.1
20b4.1bd8:     SizeOfImage:     0x6c000 (442368)
20b4.1bd8:     Resource Dir:    0x6a000 LB 0x530
20b4.1bd8:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
20b4.1bd8:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
20b4.1bd8:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
20b4.1bd8:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
20b4.1bd8: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
20b4.1bd8:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:42.262919700Z
20b4.1bd8:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T00:53:47.280000000Z
20b4.1bd8:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.613612500Z
20b4.1bd8:     FileAttributes:  0x20
20b4.1bd8:     Size:            0x1a00
20b4.1bd8:     NT Headers:      0xc0
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x562590e2
20b4.1bd8:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
20b4.1bd8:     Timestamp:       0x562590e2
20b4.1bd8:     Image Version:   6.1
20b4.1bd8:     SizeOfImage:     0x50000 (327680)
20b4.1bd8:     Resource Dir:    0x30000 LB 0x3f8
20b4.1bd8:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
20b4.1bd8:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
20b4.1bd8:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
20b4.1bd8:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x0
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
20b4.1bd8: Calling main()
20b4.1bd8: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VirtualBox fFlags=0x2
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x2): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
20b4.1bd8: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #1
20b4.1bd8: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32
20b4.1bd8: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\winsxs
20b4.1bd8: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\system32
20b4.1bd8: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' has no imports
20b4.1bd8: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe)
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=0000000077a6b630 pvNtTerminateThread=0000000077a8dee0
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child 1b24.f1c [kernel32].
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=000007fffffdf000 cbPeb=0x380
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=0000000077a40000 uNtDllChildAddr=0000000077a40000
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: uLdrInitThunk=0000000077a6b630
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Start child.
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 0 (PurifyChildAndCloseHandles) after 0 ms.
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/0: 259 ms, 30 sleeps
20b4.1bd8: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
20b4.1bd8:  *0000000000000000-fffffffffffeffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *0000000000010000-fffffffffffeffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:  *0000000000030000-000000000002bfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
20b4.1bd8:   0000000000034000-0000000000027fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *0000000000040000-000000000003efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:   0000000000041000-0000000000031fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *0000000000050000-000000000004efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:   0000000000051000-fffffffffffd1fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *00000000000d0000-fffffffffffd3fff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:   00000000001cc000-00000000001c8fff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:   00000000001cf000-00000000001cdfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:   00000000001d0000-ffffffff8895ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *0000000077a40000-0000000077a40fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
20b4.1bd8:   0000000077a41000-0000000077b3efff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
20b4.1bd8:   0000000077b3f000-0000000077b6dfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
20b4.1bd8:   0000000077b6e000-0000000077b75fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
20b4.1bd8:   0000000077b76000-0000000077b76fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
20b4.1bd8:   0000000077b77000-0000000077b79fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
20b4.1bd8:   0000000077b7a000-0000000077be8fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
20b4.1bd8:   0000000077be9000-00000000707f1fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *000000007efe0000-000000007dfdffff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffdefff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:   000000007ffe1000-000000007ffd1fff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:   000000007fff0000-ffffffffc05affff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *000000013fa30000-000000013fa30fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fa31000-000000013fab7fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fab8000-000000013fab8fff 0x0080/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fab9000-000000013fb03fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb04000-000000013fb04fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb05000-000000013fb05fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb06000-000000013fb0afff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb0b000-000000013fb0bfff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb0c000-000000013fb0cfff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb0d000-000000013fb10fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb11000-000000013fb5bfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
20b4.1bd8:   000000013fb5c000-fffff8037f957fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *000007feffd60000-000007feffd60fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll
20b4.1bd8:   000007feffd61000-000007fdffb11fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *000007fffffb0000-000007fffff84fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
20b4.1bd8:   000007fffffdb000-000007fffffd8fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
20b4.1bd8:  *000007fffffdd000-000007fffffdafff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:  *000007fffffdf000-000007fffffddfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8:  *000007fffffe0000-000007fffffcffff 0x0001/0x0002 0x0020000
20b4.1bd8: apisetschema.dll: timestamp 0x562590e2 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
20b4.1bd8: VirtualBox.exe: timestamp 0x564221d3 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
20b4.1bd8: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' has no imports
20b4.1bd8: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll' has no imports
20b4.1bd8: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Done after 282 ms and 0 fixes (loop #0).
20b4.1bd8: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1b24.f1c: Log file opened: 5.0.10r104061 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000004 g_uNtVerCombined=0x611db110
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: uNtDllAddr=0000000077a40000
1b24.f1c: ntdll.dll: timestamp 0x56259295 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
1b24.f1c: New simple heap: #1 00000000002d0000 LB 0x400000 (for 1740800 allocation)
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
1b24.f1c: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32
1b24.f1c: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\winsxs
1b24.f1c: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\system32
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv stub...
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Restoring LdrInitializeThunk...
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Returning to LdrInitializeThunk...
20b4.1bd8: Error (rc=258):
20b4.1bd8: Timed out after 60001 ms waiting for child request #1 (CloseEvents).
20b4.1bd8: Error 258 in supR3HardNtChildWaitFor! (enmWhat=5)
20b4.1bd8: Timed out after 60001 ms waiting for child request #1 (CloseEvents).
1b24.f1c: Registered Dll notification callback with NTDLL.
1b24.f1c: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll)
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll (Input=kernel32.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff pwszSearchPath=0000000000000000:<flags> [calling]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   0000000077920000 LB 0x00120000 C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll [fFlags=0x0]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   000007fefd820000 LB 0x0006c000 C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll [fFlags=0x0]
1b24.f1c: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll)
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=0000000077920000 'C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll'
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=0000000077a6b630 pvNtTerminateThread=0000000077a8dee0
1b24.f1c: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
1b24.f1c:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:43.161971100Z
1b24.f1c:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T01:09:05.164170200Z
1b24.f1c:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.613612500Z
1b24.f1c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1b24.f1c:     Size:            0x1a67c0
1b24.f1c:     NT Headers:      0xe0
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x56259295
1b24.f1c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x56259295
1b24.f1c:     Image Version:   6.1
1b24.f1c:     SizeOfImage:     0x1a9000 (1740800)
1b24.f1c:     Resource Dir:    0x14d000 LB 0x5a028
1b24.f1c:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
1b24.f1c:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
1b24.f1c:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
1b24.f1c:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
1b24.f1c: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
1b24.f1c:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:43.296978900Z
1b24.f1c:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T01:05:40.819000000Z
1b24.f1c:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.800812900Z
1b24.f1c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1b24.f1c:     Size:            0x11c600
1b24.f1c:     NT Headers:      0xe8
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x56259270
1b24.f1c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x56259270
1b24.f1c:     Image Version:   6.1
1b24.f1c:     SizeOfImage:     0x120000 (1179648)
1b24.f1c:     Resource Dir:    0x117000 LB 0x528
1b24.f1c:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
1b24.f1c:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
1b24.f1c:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
1b24.f1c:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1b24.f1c: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
1b24.f1c:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:43.047964600Z
1b24.f1c:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T01:05:40.819000000Z
1b24.f1c:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.800812900Z
1b24.f1c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1b24.f1c:     Size:            0x67c00
1b24.f1c:     NT Headers:      0xe8
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x56259271
1b24.f1c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x56259271
1b24.f1c:     Image Version:   6.1
1b24.f1c:     SizeOfImage:     0x6c000 (442368)
1b24.f1c:     Resource Dir:    0x6a000 LB 0x530
1b24.f1c:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
1b24.f1c:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
1b24.f1c:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
1b24.f1c:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1b24.f1c: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
1b24.f1c:     CreationTime:    2015-11-11T11:34:42.262919700Z
1b24.f1c:     LastWriteTime:   2015-10-20T00:53:47.280000000Z
1b24.f1c:     ChangeTime:      2015-11-18T01:04:53.613612500Z
1b24.f1c:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1b24.f1c:     Size:            0x1a00
1b24.f1c:     NT Headers:      0xc0
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x562590e2
1b24.f1c:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1b24.f1c:     Timestamp:       0x562590e2
1b24.f1c:     Image Version:   6.1
1b24.f1c:     SizeOfImage:     0x50000 (327680)
1b24.f1c:     Resource Dir:    0x30000 LB 0x3f8
1b24.f1c:     ProductName:     MicrosoftR WindowsR Operating System
1b24.f1c:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.19045
1b24.f1c:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.19045 (win7sp1_gdr.151019-1254)
1b24.f1c:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x0
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
1b24.f1c: Calling main()
1b24.f1c: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VirtualBox fFlags=0x2
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x2): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
1b24.f1c: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' has no imports
1b24.f1c: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe)
1b24.f1c: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #2
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1b24.f1c: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll)
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff pwszSearchPath=0000000000000000:<flags> [calling]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   000007fefd6d0000 LB 0x00057000 C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll [fFlags=0x0]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefd6d0000 'C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll'
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=0000000077a6b630 pvNtTerminateThread=0000000077a8dee0
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(2): New child 2524.268c [kernel32].
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: Failed to open parent process (0x000000000020b4): 0xc000000b
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=000007fffffdf000 cbPeb=0x380
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=0000000077a40000 uNtDllChildAddr=0000000077a40000
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: uLdrInitThunk=0000000077a6b630
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Start child.
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 0 (PurifyChildAndCloseHandles) after 0 ms.
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/0: 258 ms, 32 sleeps
1b24.f1c: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
1b24.f1c:  *0000000000000000-fffffffffffeffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *0000000000010000-fffffffffffeffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:  *0000000000030000-000000000002bfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1b24.f1c:   0000000000034000-0000000000027fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *0000000000040000-000000000003efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:   0000000000041000-0000000000031fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *0000000000050000-000000000004efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:   0000000000051000-ffffffffffee1fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *00000000001c0000-00000000000c3fff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:   00000000002bc000-00000000002b8fff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:   00000000002bf000-00000000002bdfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:   00000000002c0000-ffffffff88b3ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *0000000077a40000-0000000077a40fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1b24.f1c:   0000000077a41000-0000000077b3efff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1b24.f1c:   0000000077b3f000-0000000077b6dfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1b24.f1c:   0000000077b6e000-0000000077b75fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1b24.f1c:   0000000077b76000-0000000077b76fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1b24.f1c:   0000000077b77000-0000000077b79fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1b24.f1c:   0000000077b7a000-0000000077be8fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1b24.f1c:   0000000077be9000-00000000707f1fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *000000007efe0000-000000007dfdffff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffdefff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:   000000007ffe1000-000000007ffd1fff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:   000000007fff0000-ffffffffc05affff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *000000013fa30000-000000013fa30fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fa31000-000000013fab7fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fab8000-000000013fab8fff 0x0080/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fab9000-000000013fb03fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb04000-000000013fb04fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb05000-000000013fb05fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb06000-000000013fb0afff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb0b000-000000013fb0bfff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb0c000-000000013fb0cfff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb0d000-000000013fb10fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb11000-000000013fb5bfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
1b24.f1c:   000000013fb5c000-fffff8037f957fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *000007feffd60000-000007feffd60fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll
1b24.f1c:   000007feffd61000-000007fdffb11fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *000007fffffb0000-000007fffff84fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1b24.f1c:   000007fffffdb000-000007fffffd8fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1b24.f1c:  *000007fffffdd000-000007fffffdafff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:  *000007fffffdf000-000007fffffddfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1b24.f1c:  *000007fffffe0000-000007fffffcffff 0x0001/0x0002 0x0020000
1b24.f1c: apisetschema.dll: timestamp 0x562590e2 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
1b24.f1c: VirtualBox.exe: timestamp 0x564221d3 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
1b24.f1c: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' has no imports
1b24.f1c: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\apisetschema.dll' has no imports
1b24.f1c: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Done after 286 ms and 0 fixes (loop #0).
2524.268c: Log file opened: 5.0.10r104061 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000004 g_uNtVerCombined=0x611db110
2524.268c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: uNtDllAddr=0000000077a40000
2524.268c: ntdll.dll: timestamp 0x56259295 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
2524.268c: New simple heap: #1 00000000002c0000 LB 0x400000 (for 1740800 allocation)
1b24.f1c: supR3HardenedEarlyCompact: Removed heap 1 (0x000000002d0000 LB 0x400000)
1b24.f1c: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
2524.268c: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
2524.268c: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32
2524.268c: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\winsxs
2524.268c: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\system32
2524.268c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv...
2524.268c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Restoring LdrInitializeThunk...
2524.268c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Returning to LdrInitializeThunk...
```

現在までの状況を順に最初から説明いたしますと、

(0.`自動マウント`している共有フォルダにSELinuxの権限を付与しようとしてchconをしたが、共有フォルダへの権限の変更ははできなかった。)

1. ゲストOSの稼働中にマネージャから共有フォルダーの設定の編集を行った(`自動マウント`のチェックボックスを外しただけだったと思います)
2. エラーが出た（内容は覚えていません…）。
   ゲストOSのシャットダウンをしたが、起動しなくなったかと思います。
3. バージョンアップした(４系から5.0.10r104061へ)
4. タイムアウトのエラーが出て時間はかかるが起動はする（しないときもある？）。
5. 他のゲストOSを起動しようとしてもタイムアウトするようになった。（同様に時間はかかるが起動はする）

仮想マシン（マネージャ）側のエラーだと思うのですが、

- ホストOS（Windows）のコントロールパネルからアンインストールして、再インストール
- 光学ディスクの除去や`すべての警告をリセット`
- 他のゲストOSの共有フォルダーを全て解除

しても変わりませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 私も同様の現象に遭遇しています．
AntiVirを更新した後にこうなったような気がします．
4.3.10あたりの古いバージョンだと普通に起動します．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私の場合はAvira AntiVir Free (15.0.15.129) のドライバが原因でした．
もしこのアンチウイルスソフトをインストールしているのであれば，
以下の設定を行ってみてください：
1. [Manage Antivirus]→[Real-Time Protection]→[構成]→[全般]→[セキュリティ]→[製品の保護]のチェックボックスを全て外す
2. デバイスマネージャから avipbb のスタートアップを無効にする．
3. 再起動する．

この方法は[VirtualBoxのユーザフォーラム](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67840&start=195#p347694)が情報元です．

Comment: 返信が遅れまして申し訳ありません。回答ありがとうございます。
当たりでした。ネットワークから切り離して、Aviraを停止し、ゲストOSを起動してみましたら通常通りに起動しました。
ですが、avipbbのスタートアップ無効の方法が分からず、私は無料版を使用していたため、結局アンインストールしてWindows Security Essentialsを入れてしまいました。
（管理者権限のコマンドプロンプトから
`sc stop avipbb`
とした後に
`sc config "avipbb" start=disabled`
として再起動しましたが、解決しませんでした。）
Aviraを使用しており、同様の症状で困っていた方には申し訳ありません。
私の方はこれで解決とさせていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

avipbbの停止方法は
[VirtualBoxのユーザフォーラム]を読めば書いてありましたよ。

1.[コントロールパネル]→[デバイスマネージャー]
2.メニューバー[表示]→[非表示のデバイス表示]
3.[プラグ＆プレイではないドライバー]→[avipbb]を右クリックから[プロパティ]
4.ドライバータブのスタートアップ[種類]の”システム”を”無効”に設定
5.再起動